# iOS Universal links or contextual links are not working consistently in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios-simulator, xcuitest

We have solid tests for universal links, and We are using the Spotlight to open links in the simulator.

Test steps:
Open Spotlight, past the universal links, and tap enter

The expected result should be open the links in App.

The problem often opens in a browser even though the App is already installed. It is not consistent behavior. We cannot find out why links are opening in the browser. The link should be open in the App all time. The same links are working fine with an actual device. It is only happening in the simulator.

All have the same Xcode, simulator version, and another environment.

Xcode Version : Version 13.4.1 (13F100)

Comment: You may need to investigate app logs in Console, to see if there are any clues (we did the same). First of all, check if there's anything interesting for "com.apple.swc:manager". Also, check what the logs with "apple-app-site-association" say. Apart from the logs exploration, you may need to launch the app first, so the iOS understands that the app is installed (and will then open the link in it, not in the browser)

Answer (score 1):

Contextual links will not bring up the app when used from a web view component, not sure if spotlight works the same.  Answer from another team member, would it be possible to open the notes or contact app and click from there?

Comment: Yes - We tried from contact app and notes as well but no luck.